# Spring Rest Controller - business validations & resolving id

Tags: spring, rest, jpa

We are designing rest api for our existing application using spring+jpa.

want to validate the input/request payload prior to persisting. Have found `@PrePersist` listener method and hope we can validate entity business validations(unique etc) and id's can be resolved in prior to persist, however had few issues

1. `EntityManager` is not auto wired: trying to autowire entity manager in super Entity class like below so that entityManger object can be used in all subclasses

   `@PersistenceContext
   protected EntityManager entityManager;`
   Understood that since the entity is not spring managed bean, entity manager object is not autowired.
2. After setting entiy object manually (as a workaround for point 1), while trying to resolve ids based on user provided values in PrePersist callback method resulted is getting same method called recursively.

any suggestion/way to implement business validation and resolving ids based on values from jason payload for rest api would greatly appreciate.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have implemented AOP aspect to validate the rest resources prior to persisting which is working pretty good as expected.